# Bi-partitioning $2n$ points on the plane with a straight line

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, planar-partitions

Let $S$ be a set of $2n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Which is the maximum number of different bi-partitions of $S$ generated by a straight line?

More precisely, which is the maximum number of partitions $S=S_1 \sqcup S_2$ such that $|S_1|=n$ and there exists a line $\ell$ such that $S_1$ and $S_2$ and are the intersection of $S$ with the two open half-planes determined by $\ell$.

Comment: Are $S_1$ and $S_2$ meant to have $n$ points each? If not, why the restriction to an even number of points?

Comment: Yes, I just forgot to specify it. Corrected.

Comment: Could points from both $S_1$ and $S_2$ be on the line? If so, half of $\binom{2n}{n}.$ But you probably want partitions with no points on the line. I can see $2n-1$ pretty easily.

Comment: If all $\ 2\cdot n\ $ points are collinear then there is exactly one required partition. Otherwise, if $\ 2\cdot n-1\ $ points are collinear then there are exactly two required partitions.

Comment: If there are $\ 2\cdot n-2\ $ collinear points but **not** more then there are exactly three required partitions. (After this, it gets significantly richer).

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz, if the points form regular (perfect) $\ 2\!\cdot\! n$-gon then there are exactly $\ n\ $ required partitions (not more and not less). ### this should be true for all convex $\ 2\!\cdot\! n$-gon.

Comment: But a $2n-1$-gon with a point in the middle allows $2n-1$. However it sounds like much better is possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are called halving lines, and we don't know the exact order of their magnitude, just that it is between $\Omega(n2^{\sqrt\log n})$ and $O(n^{4/3})$.
For more information, see https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/open/ksets.html.

Comment: It's close, but there it is required that the line passes through two points. I believe that the answer is the same though, as one can always "displace slightly" the two points on the line. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. In fact, passing through two points is not required for halving lines according to every definition; you can find different ones in the literature.

Comment: If I remember well, in higher dimensions it might make more of a difference which definition you use.

Comment: In higher dimensions you would consider a halving hyperplane; I don't think your reasoning is valid for those.